# Linking to other pages on SwipeView Slides

Tags: javascript, mobile, hyperlink, swipeview

I implemented the touch slide using SwipeView (http://cubiq.org/swipeview) correctly but I need to go beyond and allow each image slide to link to another page.

Have you ever done this?

Please tell me how to achieve this! I've seen that in the project site someone asked the same question months ago with no answer. That's why I'm here.

This is the code as you know:

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>    

<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);

var gallery,
    el,
    i,
    page,
    dots = document.querySelectorAll('#nav li'),
    slides = [
        {
            img: 'images/1.png',
            width: 270,
            height: 365
            link: 'www.google.com,
        },
        {
            img: 'images/2.png',
            width: 270,
            height: 365,
        },
        {

    ];

gallery = new SwipeView('#wrapper', { numberOfPages: slides.length });



// Load initial data
for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
    page = i==0 ? slides.length-1 : i-1;
    el = document.createElement('img');
    el.className = 'loading';
    el.src = slides[page].img;
    el.width = slides[page].width;
    el.height = slides[page].height;
    el.onload = function () { this.className = ''; }
    gallery.masterPages[i].appendChild(el);

    el = document.createElement('span');
    el.innerHTML = slides[page].desc;
    gallery.masterPages[i].appendChild(el)
}

gallery.onFlip(function () {
    var el,
        upcoming,
        i;

    for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
        upcoming = gallery.masterPages[i].dataset.upcomingPageIndex;

        if (upcoming != gallery.masterPages[i].dataset.pageIndex) {
            el = gallery.masterPages[i].querySelector('img');
            el.className = 'loading';
            el.src = slides[upcoming].img;
            el.width = slides[upcoming].width;
            el.height = slides[upcoming].height;

            el = gallery.masterPages[i].querySelector('span');
            el.innerHTML = slides[upcoming].desc;
        }
    }

    document.querySelector('#nav .selected').className = '';
    dots[gallery.pageIndex+1].className = 'selected';
});

gallery.onMoveOut(function () {
    gallery.masterPages[gallery.currentMasterPage].className = gallery.masterPages[gallery.currentMasterPage].className.replace(/(^|\s)swipeview-active(\s|$)/, '');
});

gallery.onMoveIn(function () {
    var className = gallery.masterPages[gallery.currentMasterPage].className;
    /(^|\s)swipeview-active(\s|$)/.test(className) || (gallery.masterPages[gallery.currentMasterPage].className = !className ? 'swipeview-active' : className + ' swipeview-active');
});

</script>
```

Thanks a lot!

-Marcelo

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me on the ipad:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
  var gallery,
  el,
  lnk,
  i,
  page,
  dots = document.querySelectorAll('#nav li'),
  slides = [
    {
      img: 'img/startseite/bild-1.jpg',
      width: 1024,
      height: 721,
      desc: 'Description 1',
      link: 'http://www.google.de'
    },
    {
      img: 'img/startseite/bild-2.jpg',
      width: 1024,
      height: 721,
      desc: 'Description 2',
      link: 'http://www.heise.de'
    },
    {
      img: 'img/startseite/bild-3.jpg',
      width: 1024,
      height: 721,
      desc: 'Description 3',
      link: ''
    },
    {
      img: 'img/startseite/bild-4.jpg',
      width: 1024,
      height: 721,
      desc: 'Description 4',
      link: ''
    }
  ];
  gallery = new SwipeView('#contentslide', { numberOfPages: slides.length });
  // Load initial data
  for (i=0; i<3; i++) {
    page = i==0 ? slides.length-1 : i-1;
    // if link is set, create a-tag
    if(slides[page].link != ''){
      lnk = document.createElement('a');
      lnk.href = slides[page].link;
      lnk.title = slides[page].link;
      gallery.masterPages[i].appendChild(lnk);
    }
    el = document.createElement('img');
    el.className = 'loading';
    el.src = slides[page].img;
    el.width = slides[page].width;
    el.height = slides[page].height;
    el.onload = function () { this.className = ''; }
    // if there's a link, append the img inside the a-tag
    if(slides[page].link != ''){
      gallery.masterPages[i].firstChild.appendChild(el);
    }else{
      gallery.masterPages[i].appendChild(el);
    }
    el = document.createElement('span');
    el.innerHTML = slides[page].desc;
    // if there's a link, append the span inside the a-tag
    if(slides[page].link != ''){
      gallery.masterPages[i].firstChild.appendChild(el);
    }else{
      gallery.masterPages[i].appendChild(el);
    }
  }
  ...
</script>
```